# Emacs Searchin Number of Results

Tags: search, emacs

When doing a search in Emacs (`C-s`, incremental search), it may be useful to see the number of results. I'm trying to find a way to do that but I cannot seem to find any. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `count-matches` to get the number of matches. Incremental search is incremental, it searches incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

[ioccur](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/ioccur) incrementally lists multiple results for the regex that you provide. They are listed in another buffer, but that allows you to easily jump to each match.